# Design for Different Screen Sizes Android

Tags: android, android-layout, design-patterns, mobile

I am developing an android app but problem is, it's design doesn't remain consistent on different devices.

I studied about it on internet but finally I am stuck on the same problem.

I designed the app in Photoshop by taking the layout design of `720 X 1280` for hdpi and then also modifying it for ldpi, mdpi and hdpi.

I developed different layouts for different devices, different folders are:

```
layout
layout-small
layout-large
layout-xlarge
```

They look great on Eclipse but when i run it on real device, buttons are small [on Tablets], works fine on my phone 320 X 480, but I am not sure about other devices.

I actually mentioned the size of my buttons in dp in the layouts like:

```
layout:
android:layout_width="230dp"
android:layout_height="90dp"

layout-large 
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="125dp"
```

as they looked good in eclipse.

Comment: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820746/how-to-design-any-screen-size-and-density-in-androidmulti-screen-for-mobiles/36821546#36821546)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create different layout for different screen resolutions..
Just put your images in folder named :

```
for resolution - 320*480
=========================================
Folder Name : drawable - mdpi

for resolution - 480*800
=========================================
Folder Name : drawable-hdpi

for resolution - 540*960
=========================================
Folder Name : drawable-sw360dp-hdpi

for resolution - 720*1280
=========================================
Folder Name : drawable-sw360dp-xhdpi

for resolution - 768*1280
=========================================
Folder Name : drawable-sw360dp-notlong-hdpi
```

Comment: can you please explain your answer?  It looks like you're mixing up density with screen size.a screen size of 320 * 480 should have a layout in layout-normal not drawable -mdpi. you would place an image (regardless of size) into the drawable-mdpi folder if it's greater than 160 dpi and less than 240dpi (not dp).   Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

Answer (score 2):

For Android launcher icons you will need 6 sizes of PNG or JPG files. 
In pixels these are:

**48×48, 
72×72, 
96×96, 
144×144, 
192×192 and 
512×512**

The first five are for the App and the last one for when the App is deployed to the Google Play store.

The number of dots (pixels) per inch that an Android device’s screen holds determines how sharp the image on the screen looks. The more Dots Per Inch (DPI) the sharper the image. Android groups screen densities into several classes, medium, high, extra high, extra extra high and extra extra extra high! These are referred to as MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI and XXXHDPI. There is also a low density class, LDPI, however not many new devices have a low density screen and thus LDPI is no longer important.

**MDPI is around 160 DPI**

**HDPI around 240 DPI**

**XHDPI around 320 DPI**

**XXHDPI around 480 DPI**

**XXXHDPI around 640 DPI.**

**(LDPI is around 120 DPI).**

It is the screen density that determines the Android icon size used.

**Android Icon Size Table**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Though people usually have panic on this subject, it's not as difficult as it seems. The main patterns to follow are:

- Try to hardcode the least sizes as you can. Try avoiding, for instance, `271dp`-like codes.
- Don't use pixels, use density-independent units. That means: `dp` for layouts and `sp` for text sizes.
- As layout weights and widths, try using `match_parent`, `wrap_content` and if you need to do something proportionally, use `layout_weight`. This latter saves lifes.

Since you don't provide some specific code, it's hard to give a better advice, but as I see that you're using hardcoded sizes, a good beggining would be addapt it to those patterns.

I strongly recommend reading [this reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) as it explains exactly what you should do.

Comment: You said:"Don't use pixels, use density-independent units. That means: dp for layouts and sp for text sizes".  That's what i am using in my layout like 271dp

Comment: Yes, but you're hardcoding sizes. Using `271dp` is hardcoding, because in the device you're testing that code on will look good, but if you try at a device with a larger screen, probably `271dp` will be too small. That's what the third point is about, use things like `match_parent`, `wrap_content` and experiment a little with `layout_weight`. You have thousands of examples in google.

Comment: When I was hard coding like 271dp, I knew it will give problem. But if am using "wrap_content", then my images are same for some tablets and some phones and they don't look good. Similarly, when i use "layout_weight", I used weight but similar thing happens, looks fine on some devices but on others look very bad.

Comment: If they look bad in some devices, there must be some problem with how you defined your layout. I've tried using apps I've made having in mind the advices on the link I provided and they work just fine. I don't know how are you defining your layout, but it's just a thing of experimenting a little with them and having a bit of patience. Once you get accostumed, everything's the same on other cases.

Answer (score 0):

When you create design in Photoshop please develop design for XHDPI.
For make image resources you can use special plugins for create drawable resources in Adobe Photoshop as like http://www.cutandslice.me/
This plugin in automatic create assets for all resolution

Answer (score 0):

if you use icon for background then generate icon from this link
[icon generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html)

or if you use simple xml design view then create shap file for all screens with different size  of view