# How to create Android layout matches pixel to pixel from PSD?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, photoshop, psd

If you look at the `Question` text then it sounds duplicate but I am facing different problem here. I have couple of `psd` (given by designer). Now I need to convert them into `Android layout`. So, I followed the following approach:

- Let's assume the size of `App Bar` in `psd` is `94 px x 747px` (height x width).
- Now I convert this `px` to `dp` using [this](http://androidpixels.net/) tool.
- Let's assume I am creating `layout` for `Nexus 5`, `xxhdpi` device.
- In tool I entered the value of `px` in the front of `xxhdpi` which get converted into `33.3. dp` for the same device type.
- This value looks like very small as compare to whole psd layout. The perfect values fits to `App Bar` is `48 dp`.

I am little bit confused here. How can I use psd dimensions to create pixel to pixel android layout? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong here?" -- you are attempting to use a PSD on a pixel-by-pixel basis.

Comment: ok and How to achieve the expected result then?

Comment: Talk with the designer about how to interpret the designs to take into account varying screen physical sizes, resolutions, and densities. For example, AFAIK, there are zero Android devices with an odd number of pixels along either axis, so a width of 747px is unusable on a pixel-by-pixel basis. Presumably, the designer means something else.

Comment: @CommonsWare Lol! Can you please suggest any link where can I see How to create PSD for android which will support multiple device type (mdpi/xdpi and etc. )

Comment: I am sure that there are guides for graphic designers for how to design for mobile. I am sure that some of them cover Photoshop. Personally, I avoid working with designers that rely too heavily on Photoshop, so I do not have any particular links to guides to offer to you.

Comment: Your designer should create a LayersGroup(or psd file) for each device type/screen. Take a look at the beginning of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZejNNAK7ak), you'll see how he define a Layers for ech screen.

Comment: @AmitPal [this guide](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html) might help you. generally speaking, UI designs should be taken more as guidelines as it will be very difficult to be pixel perfect in any fragmented environment.

Comment: the designer should take mdpi device as the base and should provide you with the assets for all screen sizes as ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi such as buttons and also provide the redline documents for properly structuring the layout. [Tips for designers: from developers](http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/11/20/tips-for-designers-from-a-developer/) might help. Thanks.